# PHP get user id in url 4

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the id from my url like below

http://localhost/cpanel-ar/stage_one/reports.php?temp=temp_21day

How can GET only the "temp"?

Comment: _"how can GET only the "temp"_" -> the value of "temp" or the string "temp"?

Comment: `$_GET['temp']` will be 'temp_21day'

Comment: only string "temp"

Comment: then do an `explode("_", $_GET['temp'])[0]`

Comment: i want it as url

Comment: <select name="forma" onchange="location = this.value;">
                    <option>---</option><?php
                    $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM report");
                        while($get = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
                  
                         echo '<option value="?'.$get['rpt_key'].'='.$get['tbl_name'].'">'.$get['rpt_name'].'</option>';   
                        } 
                    ?>
                </select>

Comment: sorry, it's not clear what you actually want to achieve. And how you've tried it.

Comment: $getVars = array_keys($_GET);

    for($i =0; $i< count($getVars); $i++){
        $tbl = $_GET[$getVars[$i]];
        $get_id = $_GET[$getVars[$i]];
        $name_id = $getVars[$i];
        break;
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you mean this:

```
$getVars = array_keys($_GET);

print_r($getVars);
```

This will return an array with your get parameters.
for example:
http:example.com?getparameter=getvalue
returns:

```
Array ( [0] => getparameter )
```

Answer (score 1):

why you dont try to use `substr` function?

```
$data = $_GET['temp'];
echo substr($data,0,4);
```

its will only catch `temp`

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if i understood but you can use predefined variables using:

```
$temp = $_GET['temp'];
```

but if you are using a framework maybe they already is handle that.

if you want the 'temp' name and you know witch parameters are passed to URL you can use

```
array_keys($_GET)[i]
```

Where `i` i the index of parameter

Comment: this will get the value "temp_21day"

Comment: I want to get only the string "temp"